# Calculating sum formulas $\sum_{i=1}^{x} i^n$

Tags: number-theory

I think I've found a way to calculate a general formula for $\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{x} i^n$.
Here is how I did it:

Notice that $\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{x} i^n-{(i-1)}^n=x^n$

Here the difference of polynomials will be very useful, if we want $i^n$ to appear here all we have to do is to take the polynomials of degree $n+1$, let's see that in two examples.

A) Let's calculate $\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{x} i$, notice that we want the degree $1$ to appear, so we will take difference of polynomials of degree $2$ here as follows:

$\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{x} i^2-{(i-1)}^2=x^2$

Notice that this is the same as:

$\sum_{i=1}^{x} (2i-1)=x^2$

Here we can do some arrangements to get:

$2\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{x}i-\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{x}1=x^2$.

It is easy to see that $\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{x}1=x$, if we substitute this in we get:

$\displaystyle\left(2\sum_{i=1}^{x} i\right) -x=x^2$

and if we do the algebra here we finally get:

$\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{x}i=\frac{x^2+x}{2}$

B) Let's calculate $\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{x} i^2$, but for the sake of the post let's do that inline. We take the difference of polynomials of degree $3$ here to get $\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{x} i^3-{(i-1)}^3=x^3$, expanding the polynomials and simplifying gives us the equation $\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{x} 3i^2-3i+1=x^3$, this is the same as $3\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{x} i^2-3\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{x} i+\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{x}1=x^3$, here we have found at A) that $\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{x}i=\frac{x^2+x}{2}$, if we substitute this in and substitute $\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{x}1=x$ we get $3\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{x} i^2-3.\frac{x^2+x}{2}+x=x^3$, from this we get $\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{x} i^2=\frac{x^3-x}{3}+\frac{x^2+x}{2}$.

This method can be generalized for any $n$ as follows:

$\sum_{i=1}^{x}i^n=\frac{x^{n+1}+\sum_{i=1}^{x}\left( \sum_{j=2}^{n+1}\left({n+1 \choose j}i^{n+1-j}.(-1)^j\right)\right)}{n+1}$.

I also made a script to run the algorithm until $n=100$, and all the formulas seem to work. I was wondering if this approach is correct and is it something new.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula

Comment: Thank you @Thomas, this formula seems to be using Bernoulli numbers, I think what I do is free of any knowledge of Bernoulli numbers, am I right?

Comment: This is a correct approach but not something new, we have been using similar tricks to derive expressions for sum of power of integers. While this is not a new discovery, I think you summarize the steps nicely

Comment: Agreed that it's probably not a new discovery, however this is a nice formula and explained well by you. Welcome to math.se!

Comment: Thank you @RezhaAdrianTanuharja and Jair Taylor for your kind feedbacks :)

Comment: Kindly see [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9687) (Avoid using `\displaystyle` in title.)

Comment: @user983206 fixed it, thanks!